# Meteor Reapply Collection Transform

Tags: collections, meteor

In the latest version of Meteor, the transform functionality was added.

Example usage:

```
var myCollection = new Meteor.Collection("mycollection",
{
    transform: function(doc){ 
        doc["newProperty"] = "test"; return doc; 
    })
}
```

**Is there any way to cause these transformations to be re-calculated?**

I'm using a time humanize function (MomentJS humanize) in the DOM, and this is literally the only transform being done to the collection, so re-applying it once every 10 seconds (for about 15 entries) *shouldn't* be much of a performance hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to put your collection result in a [Dependency](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_dependency)

**Client JS:**

```
var times = [];
var timesDeps = new Deps.Dependency;

var getTimes = function () {
   Deps.depend(timesDeps);
   return myCollection.find();  //Your Query
};


Template.home.times = function() {
    return getTimes();
}

Meteor.setInterval(function() {
    timesDeps.changed();
}, 10000) //Recalculate ever 10000 ms
```

So what's being done is your collection is being called with getTimes(), and when you call `timesDeps.changed()` its reactive context is invalidated and it refreshes the data, thereby calling transform again.

Comment: Hmm I thought transforms weren't reactive?

Comment: Transforms are indeed reactive. The transform functions applied everytime `find()` is called which the reactivity methods call when data is updated, so here I manually invalidate the existing reactivity contexts within `timesDeps` every 10 seconds